# "myproject" reported a critical error: Cannot find module 'express'

Tags: express, websocket, deployment, socket.io, azure-web-app-service

I have an error when deploying my project to Azure Microsoft.
I always get `"myproject" reported a critical error: Cannot find module 'express'`

And I don't know how to install dependencies in azure or I don't know what happens

But on my PC localhost works fine

I am making a page with websocket (socket.io and express)

Comment: Update: I solved in my .deployment file i changed [config]
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true //I puted "true", and it worked

Comment: and added this other file, her name is "web.config" and  i download here https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config and i puted inside my folder project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two things you might know:

1. If you run your node project on Windows environment, then you need the `web.config` file for IIS to recognize your project, which is not necessary for Linux environment.
2. When deploying our project, we just deploy the file after debugging, so set `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true` or deploy the project after debug locally.